# Unable to fetch all values from a branch using Firebase with my AngularJs app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following db structure in Firebase and I intend to grab all values under 'users'. I am receiving an `undefined` result with the following code:

```
    fetchPharmacists() {
       var userid  = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
       return firebase.database().ref().child('users').once('value').then(
        function(snapshot) { snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
         console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
        });
       });
    }
```

Here is the image of my firebase db structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeMg5.png

Comment: Can u console the value of `snapshot` and `child`?

Comment: did you authenticated before calling this code?

Comment: @hkg328 I did authenticate using firebase.auth

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i can and i am getting 'undefined' but when i do console.log(child.key + ": " + child.val()); I see the data. Not sure why?

Comment: How do you access the consoled data? I mean In HTML

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I am storing the result in a 'User' model defined array then my template access the properties from the model.

Comment: You said that i m getting data in console! So your problem is? Unable to display data or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetchPharmacists() {
       var userid  = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
       return firebase.database().ref().child('/users/' + userid).once('value').then(
        function(snapshot) { snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
         console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
        });
       });
    }
```

I just updated your code. I think you just missed to pass the **uid** ref. Check the below reference url.

Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 0):

everyone I was able to achieve my intention with AngularFireDatabase using:

```
  this.firebasedb.list("/users").valueChanges()
```